# Visualisation with highcharter - Error with highcharter in R

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am trying to plot basic charts with library: highcharter but getting the error :

```
highchart()%>%
  hc_add_series(pokemon, "scatter", hcaes(x = height, y = weight))

Warning: Error in mutate_impl: Column `x` is of unsupported type quoted call
```

**Note:**
I was tried as per the document :
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-visualization-highcharter-r

Comment: can u check the which version of highcharter is using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's exactly wrong with your code but try this:

```
hchart(pokemon, "point", hcaes(x = height, y = weight))
```